# What are the different distinct groups of spicy

Tags: spices

I remember being told once long ago that there are 7 different types of spicy:

-Capsaicin (chilli)
-Horseradish (Wasabi)
-Ginger
-Mustard
-Cinnamon
-Garlic
-Cloves

These make a bit of intuitive sense to me (from a taste perspective), though I can't find much to back this up.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spice) breaks them up into the following 8 botanical groups:

> -Fruits, such as Cayenne pepper
>   -Roots and rhizomes, such as turmeric, ginger and galingale
>   -Seeds, such as fennel, mustard, nutmeg, and black pepper
>   -Barks, such as cinnamon and cassia
>   -Flower buds, such as cloves
>   -Stigmas, such as saffron
>   -Arils, such as mace (part of nutmeg plant fruit)
>   -Resins, such as asafoetida

[This thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/2bpjpk/eli5_why_different_types_of_spicy_food_have/) mentions different chemicals for different types of spicy and their effects on hotness (such as `capsaicin`, `gingerol` (ginger) and `allyl isothiocyanate` (wasabi)), but its not very complete.

---

My Question:

- What are the distinct chemically related spice groups?
- How would you describe each group in terms of flavour?

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64382/other-hot-spices/64384#64384

Comment: Where do you draw the line? Would you include [piperine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piperine) (black pepper) for example?

Comment: It sounds like you want us to draw consensus where there is none @Roman.

Comment: @Stephie That is a wonderful answer, thanks for linking it.  I think that is pretty much the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Roman then this question should be closed as a dupe